# How to create custom php script page

Tags: php

I'm trying to execute a PHP script which is located in home directory of WordPress.

For example **run.php**

```
<?php echo 'i run'; ?>
```

I want to run this page in URL `mysite.com/run.php` but it says 404 not found, even the `run.php` is located in that address.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Typically, WordPress does not get in the way of direct access to files like that, so long as there are no naming conflicts, so I suspect something peculiar about your site. That is a different question that whether this is a good idea or not, and it usually isn't. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish in more detail.

Comment: Generally speaking there are 2 (good) options in Wordpress: 1) Put in (your) code to execute in the functions.php file of the active theme (located in wp_content/themes/<theme name>/ OR 2) Make a plugin and put your code in the plugin and activate the plugin. I would recommend start reading here... http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add custom page in WordPress, you need to add your custom PHP file into currently activated  theme ( */wp-content/themes/* ) folder.

Suppose you have child-theme. Put the file to child-theme folder. Then goto page section, Click **Add New**.

In Page Attributes, Choose Template as your PHP File.

Open the Page.php file, It's available from the theme folder. Copy the all thing except header and paste it into your PHP file. Your PHP file must need following codes.

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            // Include the page content template.
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
            }

            // End of the loop.
        endwhile;
        ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->

    <?php get_sidebar( 'content-bottom' ); ?>

</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate the file in your theme folder.

In case someone here would like to run a php script accessing wp functions, it's necessary to require `wp-load.php` as described [here](https://www.infocaptor.com/how-to-integrate-wordpress-with-custom-php-script-or-application).
Here is some code to get you started:

```
<?php
// get path to wp-load.php from current script
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );    
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 0 == $current_user->ID )
        echo "hello not-logged-in";
    elseif (!in_array('administrator', $current_user->roles)) 
        echo "hello user";
    else
        echo "hello admin";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers you got are OK but if you really want to use the custom PHP file in root of WP installation (for a special page, API, or something else) without using a standard template or AJAX file, then you need this:

```
<?php
/*
 * This is your custom PHP file, use it for whatever you want.
 */
 
/* Disable WP theme for this file (optional) */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

/** Sets up the WordPress Environment. */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-load.php';

/* ====================================

PUT ANY PHP CODE YOU WANT HERE 

======================================= */
```

Generally, by calling `wp-load.php` you are loading a complete WordPress core into that PHP file. The only thing left is to rule with him and that's it.